# What is the difference between ‘up a tree’ and ‘on a tree’?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I saw the puma up a tree.

I saw the puma on a tree.

So, what is the difference between ‘up a tree’ and ‘on a tree’?

Answer (score 2):

"Up a tree" shows the puma has climbed up the tree, and you can now see it somewhere in the tree, above the ground level.
"On a tree" sounds a little strange. It gives the impression the puma is sitting on the very top of the tree; you'd usually be much better off saying up a tree or in a tree.

Comment: But you can say the puma is **on** a branch of the tree.

Comment: And fruit, leaves, branches, and bark belong on trees.

Comment: @JustinStafford In that sense of *on*, it means *covering the surface of* or *attached to*. It would make little sense (normally) to apply that meaning to a person. (Maybe if they were glued or stapled to a tree . . .)